# Dropping column gives unexpected result in Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes

```
df1 = {'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], '2020': [3, 4, 3, 8, 4, 5]}
df2 = {'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], '2021': [30, 40, 30, 80, 40, 50]}
df3 = {'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], '2022': [31, 41, 31, 81, 41, 51]}

listOfDf = [df1, df2, df3]
```

Then I add them side by side

```
sideBySideDataframe = pd.concat(listOfDf , axis=1)
```

Which gives me this

```
    2020    col1    2021    col1    2022    col1
0   3       'a'     30      'a'     31      'a'
1   4       'a'     40      'a'     41      'a'
2   3       'b'     30      'b'     31      'b'
3   8       'c'     80      'c'     81      'c'
...
```

Now, I only want to keep `col1` once. So I tried to delete `col1` by index

```
sideBySideDataframe = sideBySideDataframe.drop(sideBySideDataframe.columns[[1, 3]],axis = 1)
```

However, this deleted me *all*  `col1` columns. I tried

```
sideBySideDataframe = sideBySideDataframe.drop(sideBySideDataframe.columns[[1]],axis = 1)
```

with the same effect. However, when I use

```
sideBySideDataframe = sideBySideDataframe.set_index('col1')
```

I get

```
                  2020   2021   2022
col1
('a', 'a', 'a')   ...
('a', 'a', 'a')
('b', 'b', 'b')
('c', 'c', 'c')
```

My output should be

```
                  2020   2021   2022
col1
'a'               ...
'a'
'b'
'c'
```

Sooo, I am not sure why `pandas` deletes all `col1`, even if I only reference `col1` by `index`. Is there a way to only keep one duplicated column name when doing `pd.concat(listOfDf , axis=1)` or how would I set the index, so that it does not add all the values from each column where the name fits `col1`.

Comment: It's unclear what you want your output to be, but you're probably looking for a merge, not a straight concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you set `col1` as index, then concat:

```
sideBySideDataframe = pd.concat([d.set_index('col1') for d in listOfDf], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      2020  2021  2022
col1                  
a        3    30    31
a        4    40    41
b        3    30    31
c        8    80    81
c        4    40    41
d        5    50    51
```

Comment: Thats it. Can you explain why pandas is deleting all the columns, eventhough I specify only one column by index?

Comment: Your code still resolves to `drop('col1')` because `df.columns[[1,3]]` contains `col1`. That's also why duplicated column names should be avoided.